# Telebot проблемы с текстом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу Telegram-бота на библиотеке telebot (pyTelegramBotAPI), так и не понял как сделать жирный текст, при отправке сообщения. Читал про markdown, но не смог разобраться. Мой код:

```py
rasp_pn = ['Информатика **8:00-9:20** \nКазахский язык и литература 9:25-10:45\nМатематика 11:05-12:25\nКураторский час 12:30-13:50 (бывает редко)']

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "button_pn": 
        msg = (rasp_pn)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не передаёте параметр parse_mode, если он не передан, то сообщение будет отправлено как обычный текст.

```py
rasp_pn = ['Информатика *8:00-9:20* \nКазахский язык и литература 9:25-10:45\nМатематика 11:05-12:25\nКураторский час 12:30-13:50 (бывает редко)']

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "button_pn": 
        msg = (rasp_pn)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, msg, parse_mode='Markdown')
```